# Alt+= does not show me equations

Tags: microsoft-onenote-2013

I am currently using Onenote 2013, and I want to stop reaching for the mouse to insert an equation.

As I know, if I press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>=</kbd>, math mode begins, and as I type the equation, it would automatically change, like, when I write `x_i` and press space then `i` should appear as subscript.

In short, it does not work.

If I go to the ribbon menu, and then click *Equations* to insert one, type `x_i`, press space, then it would work properly. but when I press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>=</kbd>, all it does is to change the font into fixed width.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It's working for me.  Can you clarify if the behavior you are seeing is:

a)  Hitting "Alt + =" doesn't enter "Equation mode"

b)  The "Equation mode" shortcut works, but typing x_i while in this mode doesn't subscript the i.